# CSS - Using Portrait images to display inside a circle without distoring

Tags: css

I have the following:-

**HTML**

```
<div class="profile-picture">
  <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/239779/154705646/stock-photo-portrait-of-real-man-face-looking-at-camera-on-blue-background-154705646.jpg" alt="Profile - James Hales">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.profile-picture img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 392px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

I want the profile picture to be a perfect circle with the image placed inside. Is there a way to essentially crop the image with CSS so that it would take 'x' amount of pixels off the bottom so that the image displays inside a circle without distorting the image?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a41t4qng/)

Comment: How about this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/407/

Comment: Exactly that @NenadVracar - thanks

Comment: Why not use a CSS background image instead?

Comment: When using the object-fit property you have to take care of browser support. (Internet Explorer + Edge doesnt support that property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways to realize what u want. The second shows the image centered instead of vertical aligning on top.

```css
.profile-picture {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.profile-picture img {
    position:absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;    
    max-width:100%;
}

.centered img {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-picture">
  <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/239779/154705646/stock-photo-portrait-of-real-man-face-looking-at-camera-on-blue-background-154705646.jpg" alt="Profile - James Hales">
</div>
<div class="profile-picture centered">
  <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/239779/154705646/stock-photo-portrait-of-real-man-face-looking-at-camera-on-blue-background-154705646.jpg" alt="Profile - James Hales">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit` but [`support`](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit) isn't great

```css
.profile-picture {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-picture">
  <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/239779/154705646/stock-photo-portrait-of-real-man-face-looking-at-camera-on-blue-background-154705646.jpg" alt="Profile - James Hales">
</div>
```

Or you can set `img` as background

```css
.profile-picture {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/239779/154705646/stock-photo-portrait-of-real-man-face-looking-at-camera-on-blue-background-154705646.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-picture"></div>
```

Comment: Note also it sizes the image slightly differently. But it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that. Of course the container has to be square to start with.

```css
.profile-picture {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-picture">
  <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/239779/154705646/stock-photo-portrait-of-real-man-face-looking-at-camera-on-blue-background-154705646.jpg" alt="Profile - James Hales">
</div>
```